# PHP headers issue on server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I recently moved from godaddy to letshost.ie for my web hosting. However, none of my scripts would work on the new letshost server.

So I did some tinkering and here's what I found:

When a php header function is used in the same file as a php include, an error is thrown. The header function to redirect will only work if there are no includes in the script.

The following script:

```
<?php
     include ("div.php");
     header("Location: redirect.php");
?>
```

can be viewed [here](http://michaeloneill.ie/header/withinclude.php). The error I get is

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/michae28/public_html/header/div.php:2) in
>   /home/michae28/public_html/header/withinclude.php on line 3

The following script, attempts to perform the same redirect with the header function except it does't have a php include. It works fine.

```
<?php

    header("Location: redirect.php");

?>
```

This can be seen [here.](http://michaeloneill.ie/header/noinclude.php)

The lets host support team have been unable to help me. One engineer suggested there may be something wrong with my .htaccess file. I haven't changed my .htaccess file at all so I don't know how this could be causing any problems.

Here it is incase anyone can see any problems:

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName michaeloneill.ie
AuthUserFile /home/michae28/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/michae28/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

No whitespace is at the end of my file.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are not able to do `header(...)` after the moment you begin to produce content. Just put `header(...)` before your include.

Comment: Read your error message carefully: `headers already sent by (output started at /home/michae28/public_html/header/div.php:2) ` So what is line 2 of your div.php file?

Comment: Just a question, why do you need to display ANY HTML or output if you're redirecting immediately?

Comment: The issue still occurs when the php include doesn't print out any html. Above is just a bad example. In another app I have a php file with all my db connection info and when I include it, I get the very same errors.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a `header()` call if you have already output something.

As seen on you error (`headers already sent by (output started at /home/michae28/public_html/header/div.php:2)`)  check line 2 of div.php, that lines prints something

Answer (score 0):

This error commonly occurs when output is sent to the browser before a redirect.  Check your include file 'div.php' and see if there are any echo statements.

Comment: I have a php file on the server with all my db connection info and when I include it, I get the very same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Header statements have to be used before any html code.

Source:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

In your code, it sends output **This is included. No Redirect.** to browser and after that you are using `header()` to redirect. *So it will not work*. You'l have to change order or `header();` and `include`.

```
header("Location: redirect.php");
include ("div.php");
```

*But it will redirect always to `redirect.php`*

Comment: I have a php file on the server with all my db connection info and when I include it, I get the very same errors. In this case, no html code is outputted

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is simple PHP. Normal output is unbufferered. It is sent to the client as soon as it is generated. In that vein, you can't send *another* response code to the client after you've started on your 200's content.

The fix is simple enough. [Buffer your output](https://www.php.net/ob_start) if you think you need to change direction halfway through the script.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include ("div.php");
    header("Location: redirect.php");
```

But that's still starting a buffer and partially filling it. It's bad logic if you can get halfway through the output before you realise you actually need to redirect. It's a waste of CPU. The best method is to move all the logic that could dictate a redirect to before any content is generated.

A decent MVC (or other) framework will handle the business logic before it starts on presentation.